# findViewById returns null for WebView in android studio 1.1

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I build one android app which consists of one webview. I use Android studio 1.1. The minimal SDK is 19. Only one layout, activity_main.xml in the following code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"   android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">
<WebView android:text="@+id/web_view" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

java class MainActivity.java as following:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private WebView web_view;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    web_view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    WebSettings webSetting= web_view.getSettings();
    webSetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web_view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    web_view.loadUrl("file:///andorid_asset/www/index.html");       

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Error is java.lang.NullPointerException from onCreate function at 
 statement WebSettings webSetting = web_view.getSettings(), 
I already checked the variable web_view is null so that means the statement  findViewById (R.id.web_view) did not return anything.  As you see, the webview exists in layout xml file, the right layout file is called in codes (in fact only this layout xml). I really don't know what happens.  I do read the link [findViewById returns null for WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942941/findviewbyid-returns-null-for-webview). I also clean/rebuild project several times, restart my device (Samsung Galaxy TAB S, android 4.4.2) several times. It's no avail.
Can somebody point out what's wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank all of your suggestions. After I change to "id", it works. This site is really helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining the id attribute of your `WebView` wrong.

You have:

`WebView android:text="@+id/web_view"`

it should be:

`WebView android:id="@+id/web_view"`

Comment: ^ I would have stared at this for hours without seeing that.

Comment: @BojanKseneman because `@+id`, `@id` and `@string` are all `int`

Comment: hate when I write an answer late xD

Comment: I know they are all references to an int in R.java, what I meant was setting text to a webview... that's not the best idea and should throw some exceptions. :////

Comment: What is even more surprising is that `WebView` does not `extends` `TextView`, so why is `android:text` even an option?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the tag name:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"   android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">
<!-- BAD PROPERY NAME HERE -->
<WebView android:id="@+id/web_view" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

from `android:text="@+id/web_view"` for `android:id="@+id/web_view"`

Comment: How is this different than my answer? What else does it provide?

Comment: just was writing when u posted